# Using Static Maps in free Unity3D based game

Tags: unity-game-engine, static, maps, key

we are creating a free game that like Pokemon Go, has their roads from their surroundings reflected in the game so you can move around on them.

We built the game using Unity3D and Google static maps API.

Our concern is their is a huge cost if we exceed downloads with a key.

Question:

- Is there a free way to get unlimited maps or road details?
- Is a key required since each user has their own IP? We noticed it seems to work fine without a key but we are not certain of any restrictions on this.

Would love some good advice and pointers!!

Thanks,
--Mike

Answer (score 0):

> Is a key required since each user has their own IP? We noticed it
>   seems to work fine without a key but we are not certain of any
>   restrictions on this.

Google Map will always work without a key but there are few limitations such as map resolution when using it without a key. The free version is made for ordinary users. There is also request limit per day without a key. So, once your player hit that threshold, they won't be able to make more requests.

*You need a key(paid version) since this is used for commercial purposes.*

You will likely violate the Google Maps Terms of Service if you use this for a commercial purposes without a key.

> Is there a free way to get unlimited maps or road details?

No, there is no such thing as unlimited maps with Google Maps. You pay by how many request is made with your key. Another option you have is the **OpenStreetMap** which is free. I haven't used this and can't say how good it is.

Comment: Daily limit is 25,000 map loads per day.

A single user would never hit this right? If resolution is the only issues, sounds like going without a key would be the right way to go given this is a free application?

Comment: Please read the part of my answer in italic **"You need a key(paid version) since this is used for commercial purposes"**. This is not an open source game. You plan to release it then possibly put ads or in-app purchasing in it.  You are making a commercial product. It's up to you and your team to do this right. Use key or go with OpenStreetMap.